# One of my guild members cannot be found by bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I created a bot to carry out simple tasks in my server. I have 3 members, just me and my friends.

I use `guild = client.guilds.cache.get("guildid")` to get the guild object and `guild.members.cache.get("userid")` to get the member object. This works fine for me and one of my friends, but the other one returns none. I have triple checked if the ID is correct and it is.

Does anyone know why my bot can't detect him? He's been here for months so it's not a new member problem.

Comment: Not every guild/member will in cache. You're better off fetching then relying on cache

Comment: Ok ill give that a go thanks

Comment: @Elitezen How would I add a role to a fetch object. Using member you just `member.roles.add(role)` but with fetch its a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Elitezen mentioned, the reason might be that the user is not cached so you will need to `fetch()` instead.

`guild.members` returns a [GuildMemberManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) that has a [`fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method. According to your comment, you already know that it returns a promise instead of a GuildMember, so you need to resolve it first.

You can either use [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("guildid")
guild.members.fetch("userid")
  // the fetched member is available inside this "then"
  .then(member => {
    member.roles.add(role)
  })
  // log if there was an error
  .catch(console.error)
```

Or you can use async/await; just make sure the "parent" function is an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("guildid")
try {
  const member = await guild.members.fetch("userid")
  member.roles.add(role)
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```